# Promotion Impossible: Buy 6 each of 6 designs, get 10% off. But we have 1000 designs

Tags: promotions

I'm trying to create a promotion where a customer gets a 10% discount if they buy 6 units of 6 different designs. This is out of 250 possible designs. With the promotion rules in standard Magento limited to conditional blocks I am having a hard time figuring this one out.

As it is, I would need to set an overall "any" condition and then below that check all of the possible combinations of 6 using "all" conditions. The problem with this is that in a pool of 250 total items there are 319195444750 possible combinations of 6 (250choose6).

It would not be possible for me to click all of those into the condition section of the promotion.

Is there an extension that might help? Is there a way to get "if 6 of the following are true" instead of "if all/any of the following are true"? That would bring it down to 250 things to check instead of 319195444750.

Comment: How are the designs differentiated and does the promotion also apply if it is 6 of the same design?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking this. You can do the following:

- Create a category, set it to not be displayed in navigation
- Create the promotion rule to apply if Quantity >= 6 for items in that category

Here's my working configuration:

[image]

In the image it's important to use 'contains' as it seems that the 'is' condition will only apply if the product is exclusively in the category. The id is prefilled by selecting the category from a dynamically loaded menu.

Best of luck.

Comment: Category "Is One Of" should be better since otherwise it would match category id 13

Comment: Ahhhhhh true. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

In this condition, if I add 6 products from category 3 and then add another 2 products from category 2 (for example), the discount will be applied to the category 2 items too (as the condition has been met), whereas one would want discount to only be applied on category 3 items.

Would definitely like to know how to go about this.

Best,
Vipul